# yii Tipsy tooltip css does not work while using in ajax popup?

Tags: yii, jquery-tooltip

I am using [Tipsy tooltip](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jquery-tipsy/)
in a popup which loads on ajax call. In such case the tooltip css does not work. The widget load the css file but does not work.

Here is my code :

```
<a id="north-west" href="#" original-title="Click on this">Click me</a>

<?php
$this->widget('application.extensions.tipsy.Tipsy', array(  
  'trigger' => 'hover',
  'items' => array(
    array('id' => '#north-west', 'gravity' => 'sw'),
  ),  
));
?>
```

Comment: can you show us some example?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you load via ajax you would use 'renderPartial' instead of 'render'. There is one catch though: If you have javascript in it you need to make sure the processOutput parameter is set to TRUE. Basically the call would be:

```
$this->renderPartial('view', array(<data>), FALSE, TRUE);
```

Yii would then make sure the javascript is also returned, it normally does not do that with a partial. This is only required for ajax calls where the renderPartial is the only output you do, not for calls to it during a regular request.

Comment: Render for your page initially, but what action generates the code you posted above? Surely not render, as that would add the entire layout as well?